# How to add another query to a query

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How to add another query to a query

```
$OUpath = 'ou=users,ou=random,dc=test,dc=com'
$idlessUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!employeeID=*)" -SearchBase $OUpath
$idlessUsers |
    select DistinguishedName, Name, UserPrincipalName |
    Export-Csv -NoType c:\temp\employeeID.csv
```

I would like to add this to the upper query:

```
$currentdate  = Get-Date

$numberofdays = -180

$idlessUsers = Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter "(!employeeID=*)" -SearchBase $OUpath

$idlessUsers = Get-ADuser -Filter "enabled -eq 'true'" |
               -SearchBase $OUpath  -Properties LastLogonDate,lastlogontimestamp |
               Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -lt $currentdate.AddDays($numberofdays)} |
               select samaccountname, DistinguishedName |
               Export-Csv -NoType c:\temp\employeeID.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the property Enabled to the LDAPFilter, you need to use the `userAccountControl Attribute` to see if the `UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE` bit is not set.

```
$refDate     = (Get-Date).AddDays($numberofdays)
$ldapFilter = "(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(!employeeID=*))"
$idlessUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter -SearchBase $OUpath -Properties LastLogonDate | 
                    Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -lt $refDate} | 
                    Select-Object  SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, Name, UserPrincipalName | 
                    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\testirun12.csv' -NoType
```

To clarify the LDAPFilter:

`(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)` means to filter ADObjects that are NOT disabled.
`(!employeeID=*)` means to filter users that do NOT have an employeeID set.
Both filters are then combined using `(&(..)(..))`

If you want to search for users that have logged in ***within*** 180 days, change the `-lt` to `-gt` in the `Where-Object` cause.
This was unclear in your question.

---

A good site that shows all about the `userAccountControl` can be found [here](http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-userAccountControl.htm).
They also have examples of frequently used LDAP queries [here](http://www.selfadsi.org/ldap-filter.htm#BitAndOr)

Perhaps also have a look at [this site](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-write-ldap-search-filters-792496933.html) to learn about how to combine LDAP queries using `(&(..)(..))` for **AND** and `(|(..)(..))` for **OR**

Comment: So i want to get users who are logged in within 180 days and don't have an Employeed in Active Directory

Comment: @Sheikku In that case just change the `Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -lt $refDate}` to `Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -gt $refDate}`. Your own code however suggested otherwise.